# Search query in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, react-redux

Hi I'm making a small app with React and MongoDB
I don't get how to make a search query

example:

```
http://localhost:5000/api/todolist/
```

I tried (and search)

```
http://localhost:5000/api/todolist/?q=MYTEXTTOSEARCH
```

but doesn't work.
Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Is that search by query functionality implemented on the server side ?

Comment: thanks for the answer . I have no idea, I suppose yes

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your query or what you're trying to achieve you can use mongodb's [`$regex`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex) or [`$text`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text) expressions to search for text in addition to setting a "[text index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/)"

Comment: hi!
Thanks I'm using simple text coming from a variable

Comment: @MarcoDisco do you know the field you're trying to search? are you doing a text search or trying to search an exact match with the given value?

Comment: I have an array on mongo and I just would like to make a simlpe text search , nothing specific

Comment: if you expect the search term to be an exact match / one of the entries of the array then you can simply use `{arrayField: inputValue}` otherwise you would need to define a text index for that field and use `$text` as explained in the answer

Comment: just follow the docs, otherwise you need to show some code regarding your existing mongo query, input and what the expected result should be

Comment: what I got is the MongoDB has already a build in search (various)
Now I got what you meant.
I made a few tests but nothing 
Example: [`http://localhost:5000/api/todolist/?q={DB_FILED: {$regex::"WHAT_I_NEED_TO_SEARCH"}}`] 

whatever I put in it always gives me all the DB
If you have any idea, thanks!

Comment: @MarcoDisco don't pass the entire database query in the url, thats won't work probably because of url encoding and its an easy way to make your system insecure and easy to hack.

Just pass the search word via the url from the frontend and the backend should then construct the mongo query from it. You can also use GUI tools like Robo 3T or mongo compass to test the queries directly against mongodb

Comment: this is just the test with postman the App it's different but the concept is the same, at least I think